# Running ruby code in markdown editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, contentful, contentful-management

How can I run ruby code in markdown editor? I am using eRuby as templating system for my RoR app. My registration form is in contentful cms where I am using markdown approach.[Sample image for contentful markdown approach.](https://images.contentful.com/256tjdsmm689/793cMyGl3Oo0icuMAMg2mu/2b55933615b245c965523c9d7afd16b3/ui-extensions-sdk__appearance_tab.png)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a misunderstanding what Contentful is. Contentful is a Content Management System, it's not meant to store application code nor templates. A registration form should be kept out of and content storage so editors don't inadvertently introduce bugs, or worse, security issues into it.

I'd recommend using Contentful only for things that a non-technical editor would want to change, everything else should be part of your Ruby on Rails application.

Comment: Yeah..you are right. I would do so btw thanks for the info!